# Raspberry Pi 3 needs to be shut down/restarted by Android phone via bluetooth

Tags: android, bluetooth, raspberry-pi

I am working on a side project which involves a Raspberry Pi 3, RN4020 Pictail bluetooth module, and an Android application. I need to be able to shutdown/reboot the Raspberry Pi via the Android application through bluetooth. So far I have created a switch that takes care of the shutdown sequence and rebooting, but I am running into issues with reconnecting to my android phone after rebooting. Can anyone with a bit more experience with RPi3 shed some light on this for me? Thank you!

Comment: I would be interested why you chose an external BLE module over the on-board bluetooth module.  Also your question lacks detail what bluetooth is used for in this scenario.

Comment: A requirement for this project is to completely turn off the RPi3 from an Android application. I decided to use an external module because I didn't think it would be possible to communicate with the bluetooth on the RPi3 once it is powered down. The external module allows me to set a pin high which triggers a switch and boots up the RPi3.

Comment: Bluetooth is being used to communicate between the Android application and the RPi3. For example, send a command from the Android phone to power down the RPi3, capture an image through a camera connected to the RPi3, then transfer it to the Android application.

Comment: "The external module allows me to set a pin high which triggers a switch and boots up the RPi3.": Sounds like you solved your problem. You could describe the solution in more detail in an answer.